# Open external application with passing parameters using delphi application

Tags: delphi, exe, delphi-7

Actually I have one custom application and wanted to pass some values to that .exe and after that it should get executed on some event ex. it should generate files automatically.

```
unit fExecuteExe;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ShellApi;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  filename: String;
begin
  filename := 'C:\Testsrc\MojaveD5\Tools\AliasToDataview\Alias2DV.exe';
  ShellExecute(handle,'open',PChar(filename), '','',SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;

end.
```

**Delphi Form**

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 179
  Top = 116
  Width = 495
  Height = 294
  Caption = 'Form1'
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 176
    Top = 96
    Width = 113
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Run Alias2Dataview'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
end
```

Is there any way that I can open this application (image provided below) and pass some values to its textboxes and click it's buttons?[image]

This application is not supporting command line. And unfortunately I only have it's .exe, not code.

Comment: Automate it using UI Automation.

Answer (score 4):

Firs of all do not use ShellExecute, because you do not know the result. You could use

```
// Runs application and returns PID. 0 if failed.
function RunApplication(const AExecutableFile, AParameters: string;
  const AShowOption: Integer = SW_SHOWNORMAL): Integer;
var
  _SEInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
begin
  Result := 0;
  if not FileExists(AExecutableFile) then
    Exit;

  FillChar(_SEInfo, SizeOf(_SEInfo), 0);
  _SEInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo);
  _SEInfo.fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
  // _SEInfo.Wnd := Application.Handle;
  _SEInfo.lpFile := PChar(AExecutableFile);
  _SEInfo.lpParameters := PChar(AParameters);
  _SEInfo.nShow := AShowOption;
  if ShellExecuteEx(@_SEInfo) then
  begin
    WaitForInputIdle(_SEInfo.hProcess, 3000);
    Result := GetProcessID(_SEInfo.hProcess);
  end;
end;
```

If application supports no command line parameters, you could automatize what you want.

For example: Run application want wait for its window to appear. Then enumerate child windows, then when you have handles, you can do everything: set text, click buttons, etc.